# Returning a string or an Int depending on input

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

How do I write a function that takes as input an `Int` and returns that `Int` if it is `> 0` or otherwise return  a dash `"-"` if it is `< 0`. I understand that Haskell is strict with its types, but is there a way around this?

Comment: This requires a dependently typed language. Alternatively I suggest using a `Maybe Int`. Have you heard of `Maybe` ?

Comment: On the one hand, the spirit of StackOverflow tempts me to write an [answer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html#t:Dynamic) or [two](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce); on the other hand, the spirit of pedagogy tells me this question occurs mostly to beginners who would be damaged by the answer...

Comment: @DanielWagner Perhaps a self-answered-question would be beneficial for a higher level canonical answer to this. I've seen several similar questions of this nature (and run in to the same problem myself). You could also add warnings in the answer to dissuade newcomers to the language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell is statically typed meaning that normally you cannot change the type depending on runtime content.

You can however use the [`Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either) type:

```
fun :: Int -> Either Int String
fun x | x > 0 = Left x
      | otherwise = Right "-"
```

`Either` is defined as:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

You can then later in your program query whether you are dealing with the left constructor or the right constructor.

Answer (score 6):

I think the Haskell way of doing this would be using `Maybe`.

```
positive :: Int -> Maybe Int
positive x | x >= 0 = Just x
           | x < 0  = Nothing
```

Then, you can pattern match to see if you got a `Just` or a `Nothing`. Otherwise, there is no way of writing a function that does what you say - what would its signature be: `Int -> Int` or `Int -> String`?

Answer (score 5):

Functions in haskell are required to return a single type. You can argue about whether this is beneficial (see [this Programmers.SE post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105662/is-return-type-only-polymorphism-in-haskell-a-good-thing)) but without delving into much more complicated parts of the language it is what you must deal with.

Much like @pdexter mentioned in the comments and @Alec mentioned in his answer, a [`Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html)  is the best way to handle this.

```
import Data.Maybe
...    

f :: Int -> Maybe Int 
f num 
 | x >= 0 = Just num
 | x < 0  = Nothing
```

Then in your other code you can handle the `Maybe`:

```
-- Let's assume you want to bind the result to a String type
let num = f Number
putStrLn $ case num of 
  Just x  -> show x 
  Nothing -> "-"
```